# How to make a random binary list of lenght 67

Tags: list, random, binary, netlogo

This is my first post here (as is my first work with netlogo) so I'll try to be concise:

I'm trying to write a list for my turtles like Epstein and Axtell did in GAS (p. 73).

Until now I tried this with no results.

```
to setup-culture-tags                                     ;set variable
  let initial-culture-tags n-values 67 [ random 2 ]       ;create a random 
                                                           binary list of 67 
  set culture-tags initial-culture-tags                   ;
end
```

After making the list I would like to classify these based on the number of 0s. For example "00011" would be "blue" and "00111" would be "red".

The idea here is to give the turtles a random binary list of length 67. Then, they'll interact and change its values based on "tag-flipping": 
For each neighbor, a tag is randomly selected.
If the neighbour agrees with the agent at that position, no change is made; if they disagree, the neighbor's tag is flipped to agree with the agent's tag.

I don't know if this is a stupid question but I'm beginning to feel frustrated so I would appreciate a little help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what error you're getting here, but it looks like you may be trying to globally set a `turtles-own` variable. If `culture-tags` is a `turtles-own` variable (which it must be if you want all turtles to have their own `culture-tags` list), you must use `ask turtles [ ...` to ask each individual turtle to populate the list you want. Try this:

```
turtles-own [ culture-tags ]

to setup

  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 10

  ask turtles [
    set culture-tags n-values 67 [ random 2 ]        
  ]

  ask one-of turtles [
    show length culture-tags
    show culture-tags
  ]

end
```

To get your counts of zeroes / ones, check out the dictionary entry for `filter` and try combining it with `length`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured how to solve the problem yesterday but it was a nasty solution and I didn't like it. You were right, my problem was a observer/turtle problem. I didn't get the rithm yet. 
You solved my problem with less code and in a nicer way. Really appreciate your help.