# IFELSE [Compare the length of two separate lists] [ACT]

Tags: list, filter, netlogo, string-length

Following my question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503221/how-to-make-a-random-binary-list-of-lenght-67), I was trying to implement the code with `filter` and `length`. I think I achieved the `filter` but now I need the agents to compare their list length with other agent (activities) list. Here is my code:

```
ask agentes [
  set culture-tags n-values 17 [random 2]
  set shared-culture (filter [ i -> i = 0 ] culture-tags)  ;count 0s and 
                                                            create shared-culture
]
end

to move-agentes
  ask agentes [
    let nearest-activity min-one-of (activities) [ distance myself ] 
    ifelse any? activities in-radius sight-radius with
      [ length t-shared-culture = length shared-culture ] ;as many 0s in t-shared-culture (specified later in the setup for activities) as in shared-culture
    [  face nearest-activity ]
    [ rt random 40 
      lt random 40
      fd 0.3
    ]
]
```

Netlogo prints the next error: `"ACTIVITIES breed does not own variable SHARED-CULTURE error while activity 176 running SHARED-CULTURE"`. 
I imagine the mistake must be here: `[ length t-shared-culture = length shared-culture ]` but I don't know how to make both lists to interact.

Comment: What do your `turtles-own [ ... ]` and `activities-own [ ... ]` variable declarations look like? It seems as if your breed `activities` does not have the `shared-culture` variable. If you declare that, you can then say something like `if shared-culture = [ shared-culture ] of nearest-activity [ ...`

Comment: They don't. I was hoping I could make it work without the same variable declaration. But I see I have to do it that way. I already implemented your suggestion and It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! If you do only want to declare the variable once, you could just set it up as a `turtles-own` variable, then *all* turtles would have it, regardless of breed.

Comment: Of course. I didn't think about that either. I'm so concentrated with this that I can't think straight anymore. 
Thanks again.